# Como separar os erros de uma query em uma api expressjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express.js

Qual o método correto de separar os erros de uma query?

O código atual compara o erro manualmente com a mensagem gerada pelo mysql, no caso a query pode dar errado por várias razões, ao invés de retornar um log e erro 500 como este :

```
{
   err: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
   code: 500
}
```

retornar um erro como este :

```
{
   msg: 'Username already in use',
   code: 500,
};
```

Detalhe :

Driver mysql: mysql2

código de exemplo :

```
const register = async (username, password) => {
    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,12);
        const user = {
            username,
            password: hashedPassword
        };
        await db.query(queryRegister, user);
        return {
            msg: 'User registered with success',
            code: 200,
        };
    } catch(err) {
        if(err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
            return {
                msg: 'Username already in use',
                code: 500,
            };   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há uma forma de mudar o *output* de erro gerado pelo *driver* do MySQL. Você precisa criar alguma forma de transformar os códigos de erro em mensagens mais amigáveis.

Um exemplo para fazer isso:

```js
function beautifyError(code) {
  const dict = {
    'ER_NOT_FOUND': 'Registro não encontrado.',
    'ER_DUP_ENTRY': 'Duplicada.',
    'ER_DEFAULT': 'Houve um erro desconhecido.'
  };

  if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
    return dict['ER_DEFAULT'];
  }

  return dict[code];
}

console.log(beautifyError('ER_NOT_FOUND'));
console.log(beautifyError('ER_UNKNOWN'));
```

No seu exemplo, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function beautifyError(code) {
  const dict = {
    'ER_NOT_FOUND': 'Registro não encontrado.',
    'ER_DUP_ENTRY': 'Duplicada.',
    'ER_DEFAULT': 'Houve um erro desconhecido.'
  };

  if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
    return dict['ER_DEFAULT'];
  }

  return dict[code];
}

const register = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
    const user = {
      username,
      password: hashedPassword
    };

    await db.query(queryRegister, user);

    return {
      msg: 'User registered with success',
      code: 200
    };
  } catch ({ code, status = 500 }) {
    const msg = beautifyError(code);
    return { msg, code: status };
  }
};
```

Imagino que seja válido.